# Gifts to take from US to Sweden

Tags: sweden, gifts

My daughter is staying with Swedish relatives before a school study abroad trip.  I want to send a few gifts with her for them.  So many sites say to bring local food, but I read that you can't bring food into Sweden except from EU nations.

I need ideas for boys who are 17 & 20.  Would they like tshirts from American universities?
Couple in their 70s who just downsized.
Couple in their 40s.

(This type of question was asked on this site just last summer, but food was the main answer.)

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE!  Any EU import bans affect only things like meat, fruit and dairy products.  The suggested gifts -- candy, cookies, liquor -- are all just fine.  See: https://www.tullverket.se/en/travellers/travellingtosweden/foodstuffsbringingintoswedenforpersonaluse.4.735e3ebf11b045e6ea28000486.html